# Does the internal operation to slice influence the original slice outside?

Tags: go, slice

For example:

```
func test(requiredIp []int, i int) []int {
    requiredIp = append(requiredIp[0:i], requiredIp[i+1:]...)
    return requiredIp
}

func main(){
    requiredIp := []int{1,2,4,5,6}
    fmt.Println(test(requiredIp,0)) // output:[2 4 5 6]
    fmt.Println("original", requiredIp) // output:[2 4 5 6,6]
}
```

Why original slice has two 6 ?

Comment: Slices are backed by an array and that array is, as far as it is possible, shared by copies of the original slice that caused the array to be allocated in the first place. https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

Answer (score 3):

A slice is a `struct` type with three fields:

- A pointer to (an address of) the underlying array holding the data.
- The length ­— how many elements are there in the slice.
- The capacity — how many elements it's possible to store into the underlying array without reallocating it.

As everything in Go, slices are passed by value. This happens when you assign a slice value to a variable or when you pass it as a parameter in a function/method call.
What is pased by value (that is, copied) is that structure with three fields.
The pointer which is copied, obviously points at the same data block as the one in the original slice.

What happens in your code is the following:

1. The original slice is `[]int{1,2,4,5,6}`.
   It has length and capacity equal to 5.
2. It is passed to a functon, `test`.
   The slice available there via the function's parameter `requiredIp` is initially identical to the one which is passed in a call.
3. You reslice that slice by evaluating `requiredIp[0:i]`, and since in your call `i` equals to 0, you evaluate `requiredIp[0:0]`.
   That expression creates a slice with the backing array and the capacity of the original slice and length 0.
4. You then reslice the original slice once again — with the expression `requiredIp[i+1:]`, which, in your call is `requiredIp[1:]`.
   The result shares the backing array with the original, has the capacity 4 and the contents `[]int{2,4,5,6}`.
5. You then `append` the slice obtained on the previous step to the one obtained in the step before the previous one. That's where it gets interesting.

   Consider that the slice being appended to points at the 0th element *of the original slice* and has length 0 and capacity 5.  It means it has room for 5 elements.
   That is, the slice's backing array still holds `[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]`.

   The slice being appended shares the same backing array with the slice being appended to, just it points at the 1st element, not the 0th.

   The code of `append` sees it's told to append 4 elements and checks to see whether the target slice has enough *capacity* to hold them, and *it has.*
   So `append` merely copies `[2, 4, 5, 6]` from and to *the same* backing array, overwriting 4 elements starting from index 0 in it. Effectively, it's elements `[2, 4, 5, 6]` moved one element left.

   The resulting backing array now contains `[2, 4, 5, 6, 6]`: the first 4 element are the 4 elements which were the last, moved by one element left, overwriting what there were at indices 0 through 3.
6. You now return the reslting slice to the caller. That new slice value shares the backing array with all the slice values involved in the example, but remember that it has its length set to 4 — because the `append` appended 4 elements to the slice of length 0.
7. You print the original slice and the one returned from your function. They differ only in their length: the original has it equals to 5, and the returned from the function — to 4. The rest of their fields are the same: they both have capacity 5 and share the same backing array by both pointing its 0th element.
   The difference in the lengths explains why "the original" slice seemingly has "extra" `6` in it. In fact in has it exactly where it were left off before `test` was called.

If, for some reason you really wanted to "detach" the slice produced by `test` from the original one by forcing it to allocate the new backing array, there are several possibilities:

- Merely `append` to an unallocated slice — for instance,
  `append([]int(nil), 1, 2, 3, 4)` would allocate a fresh backing array.

  In your particular case that would not really be a solution as with `i > 0` the `append` would have to operate on a non-empty slice. This can be dealt, for exmaple, with two appends:

  ```golang
  s := append([]int(nil), input[0:i]...)
  s = append(s, input[i+1:]...)
  ```

  …or with allocating a new slice and `copy`ing:

  ```golang
  s := make([]int, len(input)-1)
  copy(s, input[0:i])
  copy(s[i:], input[i+1:])
  ```
- When reslicing the original slice, be sure to also artifically reset its capacity:

  ```golang
  return append(input[0:i:i], input[i+1:]...)
  ```

  Here, the first slice would have the same capacity as its length, `i`, and appending even a single element to it would force the `append` to allocate a new backing array, copy over these `i` elements to it and then copy over what is being appended.

Further reading:

1. https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro
2. https://blog.golang.org/slices
3. https://blog.golang.org/strings

…and actually consider starting with [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html).

Comment: ... and we can show that the returned slice from the test function contains all the value using `z := test(requiredIp, 0); fmt.Println(z[:5])` https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions `For slices, the upper index bound is the slice capacity cap(a) rather than the length`